# utf-8 type doesnt accept >129 bytes while downloading nsurlconnection

Tags: objective-c, web-services, ios5

Can Anyone please help me in finding the solution for this issue? downloaded content iws >2500 bytes but while converted nsstring returns empty.

```
   NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString string];
    //  NSMutableString *postString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];   
[postString appendFormat:@"username=%@",[strUsrName dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postString appendFormat:@"&password=%@",[strPasswrd dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postString appendFormat:@"&client_assertion_type=%@",[@"JWT"dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postString appendFormat:@"&client_assertion=%@",[strAppTknContent dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postString appendFormat:@"&spEntityID=%@",[@"http://localhost:8080/opensso"dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] ;

 NSHTTPURLResponse  *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;        
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:nsurl];
   NSData* dataRequest = [postString dataUsingEncoding: NSISOLatin1StringEncoding ]; 
    // NSData* dataRequest = [NSData dataWithBytes:strRequest];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: dataRequest];
    [theRequest setURL:nsurl];

    //// set headers
     NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"text/plain"];
    [theRequest setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSString *acceptType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/json"];
    [theRequest setValue:acceptType forHTTPHeaderField:@"accept"];
    [theRequest setTimeoutInterval:3.0];
    [theRequest setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad];        



 NSData *responseData =[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
 NSString *strUserResponse =[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
    int status =[response statusCode ]  ;
```

staus:204 but strUserResponse is empty

Comment: What does `dataRequest` actually contain?  You are converting strings to UTF-8 when appending them to `postString` and then converting that to Latin-1, so I'm not surprised the data is being truncated.

Comment: 204 is "no content", how can you expect a responseData?

Answer (score 2):

The 204 http response code means no content, `responseData` will contain nothing so it follows that `strUserResponse` will not contain the data you want.

The 204 return code means:

> Server has received the request but there is no information to send
>   back, and the client should stay in the same document view. This is
>   mainly to allow input for scripts without changing the document at the
>   same time.

Do not ignore the http return codes.

See the http response definitions: [Status Code Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Also, for debugging something like this you can use the debugger and console or NSLog to verify back stream, in this case what is the value of `responseData`.